# How do Google Play APK expansion files work, exactly?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, google-play-services

**Edit:**
In summary, Google Play APK expansion files are much simpler and much less sophisticated than I thought at first. I created a Cordova plugin which helps me use APK expansion files. My code might be useful to native implementations, too:
https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader

---

Let's say I upload an APK to Google Play with an expansion file.

- I can't find any place where I can update or delete that expansion file.
- When I upload a new APK, I don't know if I should re-upload the expansion file.

Do I have it right that expansion files are simply applied to users' current games and to new installs? It just doesn't make any sense! I need a flowchart, a picture, caveman drawings, ANYTHING!

Here are three example situations... what is the outcome?

**Situation 1**:

1) A developer publishes an app with an APK and an expansion file.

2) User A downloads that app.

3) The developer publishes the app with an APK only.

4) User B downloads the app.

Does user B have the expansion file after #4?

Does user A have the expansion file after #4?

**Situation 2**:

1) A developer publishes an app with an APK and an expansion file.

2) User A downloads that app.

3) The developer publishes the app with an APK and an identical expansion file.

4) User B downloads the app.

Does user B have two identical expansion files or one expansion file after #4?

Does user A have two identical expansion files or one expansion file after #4?

**Situation 3**:

1) A developer publishes an app with an APK only.

2) User A downloads that app.

3) The developer publishes the app with an APK and an expansion file.

4) User B downloads the app.

Does user A have the expansion file?

Comment: It's all explained here... https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: The problem is that it isn't explained clearly. I obviously looked at that page already, multiple times. I'll add an example situation to my question...

Comment: nothing wrong with this question, expansion files are tough (time consuming) to understand on the android doc (that said, its rare that android docs are unclear)  upvoted..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expansion files are downloaded with your APK, and are tied to specific versions of your APK (as determined by the `versionCode`). When you upload a new expansion file, you *must* upload a new APK with an updated `versionCode`. When you upload new APK, you can either choose to upload a new expansion file, you can choose to associate the new version with an existing expansion file, or you can choose to not associate it with any expansion file at all.

When the Play Store updates your app, it will update the app installation to match the configuration you selected for your expansion files. If you didn't change the file, it won't redownload it. If you updated it, the Play Store will download the update. If you removed the file, Google Play will delete it.

Keep in mind that [you may need to this manually](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#DownloadProcess) if the Play Store is unable to perform these operations for you. Essentially, your app should always be ensuring that the Play Store performed the correct operations and should react accordingly.

**Situation 1**

> Does user B have the expansion file after #4?
>
> Does user A have the expansion file after #4?

No and no.

**Situation 2**

> Does user B have two identical expansion files or one expansion file after #4?
>
> Does user A have two identical expansion files or one expansion file after #4?

They both each only have one.

From [the expansion file documentation on storage location](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#StorageLocation):

> For each application, there are never more than two expansion files in this directory.

The two expansion files referenced here are a main file and a patch file. Users will never have more than one of each.

**Situation 3**

> Does user A have the expansion file?

Yes.

In order to accomplish this, you will have needed to also upload an APK with an updated version code. This will trigger an update on User A's device, which will include downloading (or attempting to download) the expansion file.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on this. When we upload an APK, and then Google serves an expansion file from its servers, does the expansion file ``versionCode`` served from Google Play always match the APK's ``versionCode``? It does, right?

Comment: Not always. See the [`<expansion-version>`](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Filename) documentation- you can re-use an expansion file with new application versions without re-uploading it, so it is possible that the two don't match. However, every time you upload a new expansion file the two must match.

Comment: All right, got it. I wish Google Play would show us what the served APK filename of the new upload looks like. Would clear out a lot of the uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

After using APK files for some time, I made a Cordova plugin which does away with a lot of the manual checks that make it very error-prone and difficult to use Google Play APK expansions. (even the Android SDK's sample app framework is full of bugs -- for example, ambiguity in main/patch files) If one does not use Cordova, some of the code can be modified to fit one's needs.

All my plugin needs is a link to an included Android library, a public key from the app, and a unique expansion authority URL. (it is also global, per Google Play's design)

https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader

Comment: You'll have to check and see. I haven't made a big update in a while and people made forks for various versions.